# Первичный ключ core data

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift, coredata

Как правильно реализовать первичный ключ в *core data*?

Мой способ решения был таков: я брал в `objectID(NSManagedobjectId)` название таблиц и идентификатор `(CONTACTS_TABLES/t60CFDE16-3F38-4369-8D30-C0119AB890054)`, собственно это и являлось уникальным ключом.
Есть ли более универсальный способ организовать это?

Comment: может это поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901640/core-data-primary-key

Comment: Нужен просто уникальный идентификатор? Тогда [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString].